# Modifying script to rename uploaded images

Tags: image, rename

We have a form mailer that sends lost and found pet info to our e-mail. We also have an image upload function for sending images of the lost pets. An employee (long since gone) coded it for us. Sometimes we get multiple image uploads with the same file name (direct from camera I suspect) like "image.jpg" - thus overwriting the previous image before we can add to the listing - I would appreciate some help with modifying our existing image upload code (below) to rename duplicate files with the time and date suffix. Is this possible with what we have? I'm afraid we are not coders so may be more dependent on detail than others.

Thank you so  much!

```
/* Set upload directory */
$uploadDir = "/home/hsoet/public_html/uploads/attach";
$baseUrl = "http://www.petsfurpeople.org/uploads/attach";
$uploadFile = "";

/* Setup acceptable attachment types */
$acceptableTypes = array( 
    "image/gif", 
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/jpg"
);

/* There was a file uplaoded but an error occured.. */
if( $_FILES["attach"]["error"] > 0 && $_FILES["attach"]["error"] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE ) {
    echo "<h4>Error uploading attachment (file size too large possibly!)</h4>";
    echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
    exit();
}

/* File was uploaded, handle... */
else if( $_FILES["attach"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {

    /* Check to make sure that the file is an acceptable type */
    if( !in_array( $_FILES["attach"]["type"], $acceptableTypes ) ) {
        echo "<h4>Unacceptable attachment type.  Please try again!</h4>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
        exit();
    }

    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . "/" . basename( $_FILES["attach"]["name"] );
    $attachUrl = $baseUrl . "/" . basename( $_FILES["attach"]["name"] );

    if( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["attach"]["tmp_name"], $uploadFile ) ) {
        echo "<h4>Error uploading attachment.  Please try again!</h4>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

and it sends a link to the file to us via e-mail along with the other form info.

```
    elseif (mail($toemail,"HSOET Lost Pet Form Submission","\nEmail:     ".$fromemail."\nName: ".$name."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nType of Animal: ".$type."\nArea Lost: ".$area."\nDate Lost: ".$date."\nBreed: ".$breed."\nSex: ".$sex."\nAltered: ".$altered."\nCollar Color: ".$collarcolor."\nTag Number: ".$tag."\nPet's Name: ".$petname."\nDescription: ".stripslashes($description)."\nFile Attachment: ".$attachUrl."\nIP Address: ".$pfw_ip."",$headers2)) {
  mail($fromemail,"HSOET Lost Pet Form Submission Confirmation",$c_message,$headers);

      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0;url=".$c_url."\">";

      echo "<h4>If you are not redirected automatically, <a href=\"".$c_url."\">click here</a>.";

    } else {

      echo "<h4>Can't send email to $email</h4>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty fix would be to add a timestamp to each and every image name. Simply change the following line:

```
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . "/" . basename( $_FILES["attach"]["name"] );
```

to:

```
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . "/" . `date + "%d%m%y_%H%M%S"` . basename( $_FILES["attach"]["name"] );
```

This assumes that you are running your app on Linux.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this - I believe this would be enough to keep from overwriting. However when I replaced our line with yours it doesn't appear to be adding anything to the file name. I tried a few test uploads and the image is still being added to the directory with the original name. I am sure we are on a Linux system. What could be wrong here? I pasted your code directly. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I just checked on a test page on my system. It should definitely work. Please ensure that the date function is inside backticks (``). If possible, copying and pasting between MS and Linux systems sometimes does strange things.. If you know how, try and display the $uploadFile variable in an html element on your page, so you can see what the variable holds. I just noticed, you'll have to do the same with the $attachUrl line